# Where should a plugin create temporary files

Tags: plugin-development

I have a plugin which needs to create a temporary file. Where should I put it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[PathService](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/PathService) has a [getTempPath()](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/PathService#getTempPath-detail) method which will return the `craft/storage/runtime/temp` path by default.

Craft uses that for its temporary files and so can plugins.  Just make sure youre plugin is being defensive by giving it a unique filename or create a folder with a unique name and put your files in there, etc.

Comment: Is there a way to directly access files that are placed in the `/storage` folder? I get file not found if I try to link to it.

Comment: Access from them PHP? Or you want to link to them directly from a template? Probably worth it's own separate post.

Comment: Yeah I was trying to link to them from a template, or display it on the template (for pictures). But haven't had any luck. However, now I set up my plugin so files get saved to a location in my plugin resources folder and now able to get the files, so I might just keep this route for now.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was going to suggest anyway. :)