# Do temporary files stored in craft/storage/runtime/temp get automatically deleted?

Tags: plugin-development

This is somewhat related to the question at [Where should a plugin create temporary files](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2665/where-should-a-plugin-create-temporary-files)

I have a plugin that needs to store temporary files. Do I need to worry about cleaning up the craft/storage/runtime/temp after I'm done with them, or do they get deleted automatically on some kind of recurring basis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only two times Craft clears that folder is 1) at the end of an automatic or manual update and 2) when you have the "Temp files" checkbox checked under the "Clear Caches Tool" under `Settings->Tools`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I'll be sure to have the plugin delete the temporary files after they're used so the folder doesn't get huge.